# Ubuntu installation gets stuck while extracting downloaded files

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, windows-xp, microsoft-installer

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Netbook. I already have Windows XP and I am using the Windows Installer to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

While installing, the files are downloaded successfully (this takes about 15 minutes), but then it gets stuck halfway through extracting the files.

I tried this on another netbook with XP and encountered exactly the same problem.

Is there a way to resolve this or an alternative installation method that will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the alternative way by manually downloading the ISO file and save it to the same folder as the WUBI installer file then recheck.

More details in the following links

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts

Comment: Thanks. Do i need to do something with the iso file or just download it and put it in the same directory and then run the windows installer? I am downloading ISO file now, will take some minutes.